# Отображение километража по треку из GPX

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Загружаю на карту файл GPX записанного трека (пройденного пути):

```js
function init () {
 var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
   center: [35.908634, 56.859658],
    zoom: 10,
    controls: []
   }, {
    buttonMaxWidth: 300
 });
  ymaps.geoXml.load('http://routing.ucoz.net/qwerty.gpx').then(function(res){
  myMap.geoObjects.add(res.geoObjects);
  myMap.setBounds(res.geoObjects.getBounds());
 });
}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

```css
html, body, #map {
  width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&coordorder=longlat"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Вопрос в следующем: как по данному пути можно вывести общий километраж?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для линий есть [метод геометрии `getDistance()`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geometry.LineString-docpage/?from=SO#getDistance), который возвращает длину в метрах.

Comment: В моем случае res.geoObjects.geometry = null, поэтому метод getDistance() не работает

Comment: этот метод надо вызывать у геометрии полилинии

Comment: Как по информации из файла .gpx построить полилинию?

Comment: @Roman69 у вас в .gpx файле уже лежит полилиния, вы её отображаете на карте. [Вот пример в песочнице про работу с gpx файлами](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/tracks_compare?from=SO). В этом конкретном файле линия лежит тут: `res.geoObjects.get(0).get(0)`, соответственно её протяженность `res.geoObjects.get(0).get(0).geometry.getDistance()`